# Storing ZonedDateTime in Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, jpa, zoneddatetime

I am using `ZonedDateTime` in my JPA entities. I am also using Postgres db. By default postgres creates table schema as `bytea` column type.

Two question I have

1. Is it OK to store this info as `bytea` format?
2. If I were to do SQL comparison, let’s say I want entries greater than given date, how do I write this comparison in SQL, meaning how do I convert `bytea` back to Date?

Comment: It must store as `TIMESTAMP`. It's not related to PostgreSQL itself. Something is wrong with your architecture, perhaps your ORM's version doesn't has support to Java8 date types.

Comment: "*By default postgres creates table schema as bytea column type*" - no it does not. Postgres itself does not create any tables. This is always done by an application that sends SQL to the Postgres server. Most likely your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") does that

Answer (score 3):

First of all JPA just map basic and most common types.

Bytea is the type that postgres end up using when you declare a field of a type not supported, and there isn't an annotation to say how to treat it.
See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-binary.html.
The reasoning for using bytea is that when the type can't be mapped it assumes you want the object to be stored serialized.

At this time JPA doesn't support Java 8 types, more info on JPA standard at:
https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-java-8-date-and-time-types/

You can create a custom datatype with hibernate, some time ago i posted on this in a play framework group:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/3AtNiMf_WBM/LBMeztlXBAAJ

Bye
Hans